# C# catch control's change event from its container

Tags: c#

In my project I have a settings form. Where if any changes happen I have to notify user about it if he wants to leave that page without saving his changes. At this time I am doing this by catching every control change event. I am sure there is a better way - like catching the change event from its container. Is it possible?

Comment: Web, WPF, Winforms? Sounds like web, but can't be sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right solution, but you may want to be very generic about catching the change events.  For example, you could try something like this right after the `InitializeComponent();` line in the constructor:

```
foreach(Control c in Controls) {
    c.TextChanged += new EventHandler(genericTextBox_TextChanged);
}
```

`genericTextBox_TextChanged` would set a form-wide `hasChanged` flag to true, or something really basic like that.  You may need to make this into a recursive function that loops through all of the children of `c` if it has child controls.

Comment: what if, if there are various type of controls ?

Comment: The easiest option is to add a few "as X" lines, one for each type of control.

Comment: Do they inherit from a similar base class that has an appropriate event?  If so, you can cast to the base class.

Comment: Almost all other solutions are significantly more involved. They include using a custom attribute to specify which event to listen to, or creating custom controls that inherit from TextBox, CheckBox, etc. and expose a generic Changed event, and then using only those controls on this form.  How many different controls are you using?

Comment: NO no I just want to know if there is any bound with controls and container if any changes happen.

Comment: Doesn't this solution do that?  I can post the full recursive function for dealing with container controls and a couple different control types, if that helps.

Comment: I am already doing it. I wanted much generic solution. Thanks for reply.

Comment: As it turns out TextChanged is inherited from Control.  I have updated my solution to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than worrying about the controls directly, how about creating a Settings class that implements interfaces from System.ComponentModel like INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo and use data binding to get the values in and out of the controls.

Your Settings class can then not only record whether anything has changed but also make validation of the user input easier.

A good place to start is [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ef2xyb33.aspx).

Comment: Sound interesting. Could you please clarify it more.

Comment: The basic idea behind this to create a Settings class with properties for each settings, and have the setters on each property update a HasChanged flag for the class.  When the form is opened, you pass in an instance of Settings and bind your controls to the appropriate properties.  When the user closes the form, you can check the HasChanged flag and prompt the user if the settings have changed.  The key is to make sure you have a way to revert back if the user does not want to save, which is done easiest by making the class cloneable and working against a cloned copy until they save.

Answer (score 1):

Let me offer you some kind of a workaround. 
My offer is to create a custom DataSet. Then add tables corresponding to the form controls. After this you can bind each form control to this dataset.
Pros: You keep all the controls data-bound. So you don't need to care about the changing of particular control. You have just to control dataset changes.
 Cons (maybe): after this you should rewrite settings preview mechanism. Instead of changing controls you have to change data. IMO, it's not so hard, but I have no idea about this approach in your application
I think this approach will be, at least, easy to debug.

Comment: Some example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If it's web, look at the unload event for javascript